# .htaccess Subfolder Redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I recently moved my WordPress website to a subfolder. I want to add a redirect in the .htaccess file so that the links to images I've uploaded originally to ~/wp-content/uploads/ will pass to ~/blog/wp-content/uploads. The .htaccess file must remain in the root folder for WordPress to read it properly. This is what I tried

```
Redirect /wp-content/uploads/ /blog/wp-content/uploads
```

That worked great, except I host other domains on this account, and all of the other domain's upload folders were being redirected in a similar manner.

Is there a way to restrict this redirect to just one domain? So that *example.com/wp-content/uploads* redirects to *example.com/blog/wp-content/uploads*, but *another.com/wp-content/uploads* does not?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want a 301 redirect, using this RewriteEngine example should work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: There we go! This did it for me! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You should place the `Redirect` inside the `<VirtualHost>` definition for `example.com` in the `httpd.conf` (or equivalent) instead of `.htaccess`

on a sidenote, `Redirect`says temporary / 302 by default, so it is *nicer* to use

`Redirect permanent /wp-content/uploads/ /blog/wp-content/uploads` instead

Comment: This is really the correct answer.  If you have access to put the Redirect in your config file inside the correct domain-specific section then do that.

Comment: I would agree with this. Unfortunately, on this particular shared host I don't have that kind of access.