# redirect to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have set up url redirect on my host--but its not working.
my htaccess looks like this now

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
rewriterule ^http:\/\/www\.bangkoksoftball\.info "http\:\/\/www\.bangkoksoftball\.info\/wordpress" [R=301,L] #4d3a8d4534e567
```

what i want is any request to http://www.bangkoksoftball.info to be redirected to http://www.bangkoksoftball.info/wordpress/

but any request to a path file or directory off the root not to be redirected

this so people can still access the old site  via /home.html or index.html  etc..  and still be able to navigate outside the wordpress folder

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bangkoksoftball\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /wordpress/ [R,L,NE]
```

Remember there is **NO** presence of http/https in %{HTTP_HOST} or %{REQUEST_URI} variables. Also `.` needs to be escaped in domain match. `NE` flag is for not escaping the query parameters.

Comment: @asiaexpat: If my answer helped you, can you please accept this answer so others can also use it in future, looking for similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The rewriterule line does not look at the domain, you must specify the domain the rule applies to in the RewriteCond line. In the rewriterule line, you specify first the paths that should trigger the rule, and the path the user should be sent to instead.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http:\/\/www\.bangkoksoftball\.info$
RewriteRule ^/$ "http\:\/\/www\.bangkoksoftball\.info\/wordpress" [R=301,L]
```

This will send only requests to www.bangkoksoftball.info/ to the wordpress folder. If you want to also redirect www.bangkoksoftball.info/index.php to the wordpress folder, you would need to add an additional set of directives:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http:\/\/www\.bangkoksoftball\.info$
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.bangkoksoftball\.info\/wordpress" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ok--i dont have a www.bangkoksoftball.info/index.php  so the additional set would not be needed. what i need is any request other than www.bangkoksoftball.info not be redirected

Comment: The ^/$ portion of the RewriteRule will enforce that. THe first set of three lines should accomplish what you need.

Comment: i uploaded the updated htaccess file as specified--it doesnt work--nothing seems to have change

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you as it worked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719089/htaccess-subfolder-redirect):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?bangkoksoftball.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.bangkoksoftball.info/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: u mean replace my whole htaccess with that?

Comment: He is trying to redirect only requests to '/' to '/wordpress/', not all requests to '/phpMyAdmin/'

Comment: @Wigewhat He said he want to redirect from http://www.bangkoksoftball.info to http://www.bangkoksoftball.info/wordpress/.
@asiaexpat, yes.